# Method that scans through chekboxes in a listview

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox, android-checkbox

I am experimenting with this example project: http://schimpf.es/listview-with-checkboxes-inside/

I have added a button inside the xml file that contains the ListView.
And when it is being pressed I want a method that scans through the array of checkboxes and checks if all of them are checked.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Please add some code to help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private boolean checkBoxes(){
  for(SampleData s : dataList) if (s.selected == false) return false;
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each entry in dataList. If you get one that isn't set, return false. If they all past the test return true:

```
private boolean allChecked()
{
    for(Object item : dataList)
    {
        if (!(SampleData)item.isSelected())
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Note that dataList was defined as an ArrayList of type Object, not of type SampleData. So as you iterate each entry, it needs to be cast to SampleData.

EDIT:

To use this, change the Activity class so that 'adapter' is a class variable:

```
public class CheckboxListActivity extends ListActivity {

    //Define adapter here so that you can refer to it anywhere within the Activity
    CheckboxListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_checkbox);

        //Set the class level 'adapter' variable
        adapter = new CheckboxListAdapter(getLayoutInflater());
        getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

In your onClick, call the new method on the variable 'adapter':

```
public void onClickNeste_sjekkliste (View v) {
    boolean ifCheckedAll = adapter.allChecked();

    if (ifCheckedAll == false) {
        Log.d("CheckedAll", "false");
    }
    else if (ifCheckedAll == true) {
        Log.d("CheckedAll", "true");
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't get that to work.
It always returns false.

I put the method into the CheckBoxListAdapter.java

```
public boolean allChecked() {
    for (Object item : dataList) {
        if (!((SampleData) item).isSelected())
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and in my MainActivity I call the method when button onClick. And then I get the value of it.

```
public void onClickNeste_sjekkliste (View v) {
    CheckboxListAdapter test = new CheckboxListAdapter(null);
    test.allChecked();
    boolean ifCheckedAll = test.allChecked();

    if (ifCheckedAll == false) {
        Log.d("CheckedAll", "false");
    }
    else if (ifCheckedAll == true) {
        Log.d("CheckedAll", "true");
    }   
}
```

Comment: That's because you are scanning a brand new adapter called 'test', not the one set up in onCreate that is connected to the ListView. The intial state of a CheckBoxListAdpater is a mix of true and false, hence you always get false. You need to call the method on 'adapter'. Please see my updated answer.